# AddRow from codebehind in asp.net table does not add a row properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, row, postback

I have an `asp:Table`, have defined the header cells in `.aspx` page. Have an `AddRow` button, which when clicked should add a new row to the table.

The code is as follows:

```
<asp:Table ID="tblnew" runat="server" BorderStyle="Inset" GridLines="Vertical">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>S.NO</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>Service</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>Material Type</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAddRow" runat="server" Text="Add Row" OnClick="CreateRow" />
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
```

The code behind is:

```
protected void CreateRow(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            tblnew.Controls.Add(tr);
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                tc.Controls.Add(txt);
                tr.Controls.Add(tc);
            }
            TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = "Remove";
            tc1.Controls.Add(btn);
            tr.Controls.Add(tc1);
        }
```

Things work fine when `AddRow` button is clicked for the first time.

A new row gets added, but when I click the `AddRow` button again, another row doesn't get added. I guess I'm missing some key stuff here.

Also, I have not written any code on `Remove` button click, yet it removes the particular row when clicked, guess maybe some `postback` stuff is happening.

On `Page_Load`:

[image]

After `AddRow` button click:
[image]

Experts please help.

Answer (score 0):

Because of `PosBack` your added row doesn't persist,
You can use `ViewState`.

Or take a look at:

[Dynamic generated TableRows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243516/asp-net-dynamically-generated-tablerows-wont-persist-between-postbacks)

Or here is your answer discussed about how to generate rows of TextBoxes in ASP Table on every click of the Button and retain the entered values on `postbacks`:

[Dynamic Table Row](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/06/29/faq-dynamically-adding-rows-in-asp-table-on-button-click.aspx).

Hope this will help you.